# Using Booleans and Sentenial Logic in Python

Tags: python, boolean

Trying to come up with a code that takes names and adds up the amount of letters until you type "N" or "n" to make it stop. 
Here is what I have:

```
def main():
    namelength = 0
    name = input("Enter a name or N to stop: ")                   

    while name!="N":
        name = len(name)
        namelength = namelength + name
        name = input("Enter a name or N to stop: ")

        N = False
        if name == "n" or "N":
            N = True    
            if N == True:
                    print(namelength)

main()
```

It works with N and n, but it prints the namelength with every entry. Can't fix it. Anyone know where I went wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `if name == "n" or "N"` is evaluated as `if (name == "n") or ("N")`. When a str converts to bool it's converted to True, that's why it's always printed.

Comment: condition `if name == "n" or "N"` will check `name` is `n` or "N" where this condition will be always true. Because in python falsy values are "", {}, [], False, 0. Where "N" is truthy value.

Comment: Remove the last two lines and `print(namelength)` outside **while** loop

Answer (score 2):

You need to move `print(namelength)` to *outside* the loop if you don't want it to be printed on each iteration, and as mentioned in comments, the two lines before the `print` are redundant, remove them. Also please note the following,

The condition

```
if name == "n" or "N"
```

will be *always* satisfied since it's equivalent to

```
if (name == "n") or ("N")
```

and since `bool('N')` is `True`, you'll be always getting `True`.

---

Change it to

```
if name == "n" or name == "N"
```

or, better

```
if name in ['n', 'N']
```

or even

```
if name.lower() == 'n'
```

Comment: namelength = 0
    name = input("Enter a name or N to stop: ")                   
    
    N = False
    if name == "n" or "N":
            N = True
            
    
        
    while name!="N" and name!="n":
        name = len(name)
        namelength = namelength + name
        name = input("Enter a name or N to stop: ")
        
     
    if N == True:
        print(namelength)

    namesDan = False
    if name in ['Dan']:
        namesDan = True
        
    if namesDan == True:
                print("Wow there's a Dan")
    else:
                print("There were no Dan's:(")